# opencv and ffmpeg 0 kbyte file

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm new to OpenCV and trying to record simple video with ffmpeg, but size is 0kb everytime... I got success with Cinepak codec, but video is recorded fast, or I set fps to 4 and cwWaitKey(20).. Here is the code what I'm trying..

```
    cvNamedWindow("Webcam", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    CvCapture *cap; cap = cvCreateCameraCapture(0);
    IplImage *img; img = cvQueryFrame(cap);
    CvVideoWriter *writer;
    double fps = cvGetCaptureProperty(cap, CV_CAP_PROP_FPS);
    int camWidth = (int)cvGetCaptureProperty(cap, CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH);
    int camHeight = (int)cvGetCaptureProperty(cap, CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT);
    CvSize size = cvSize(camWidth, camHeight);
    writer = cvCreateVideoWriter("record.avi", CV_FOURCC('M','J','P','G'), fps, size);

    while(cvQueryFrame(cap))
    {
        img = cvRetrieveFrame(cap);
        cvWriteFrame(writer, img);
        cvShowImage("Webcam", img);
        cvWaitKey(20);
    }
```

//release stuff here.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thank you.

P.S I tried also other FOURCCs but still same result, file is 0 kbytes, nothing is written there.. help :(
FOURCCs tried: XVID, MP4V, FVFW, MPEG, MPG1/2, WM1/2.

P.P.S Using Windows 7 x64, installed both ffmpeg x86 and x64 versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed.. I just downloaded DIVX codec, installed it and used DIVX fourcc, works like a charm.
But I still got problems for calculating number of frames hehe :-)
10 fps would be 100 frames, but I fail with 25 fps.. doesn't work 25*10.

Comment: `wait_time = 1000.0f / fps` (in milliseconds). 10 fps means 10 frames per second, so you'd have to wait 100 ms between capturing frames, however don't ignore the additional time used for processing the image (so you essentially have to wait a bit less than 100 ms).

Comment: Hi, I'm doing like this:
[code]for(int iframe = 0; iframe < fps * 60; iframe++) //60 seconds
  {
   cvQueryFrame(cap);
   img = cvRetrieveFrame(cap);
   cvWriteFrame(writer, img);
  }[/code]
Whenever I put cwWaitKey(any ms) or Sleep(any ms) it just records damn fast. 10 seconds video was like 30% more speedy..

Comment: Your math is off. Don't multiply your fps by 60 and it should work. You're recording with 600 fps rather than 10 fps (or actually try to do so).

Comment: Well, 1 second video ain't cool. That's what it gave me the result.

Comment: Ah okay, so that would work, you just have to ensure to wait the proper time (you might want to measure the time between start and end of loop and subtract that from the delay).

Comment: Btw. an easier and more robust approach might be using a timer that fires the capture code once every x ms.

Comment: I did something like this:
int counter = 0
  while(true)
  {
   for(int iframe = 0; iframe < fps; iframe++)
   {
    cvQueryFrame(cap);
    img = cvRetrieveFrame(cap);
    cvWriteFrame(writer, img);
   }
   if(++counter == 10) break;
  }

Comment: Looks fine, you're just lacking waiting for the next frame (to not create a slow motion recording).

Comment: I used Sleep(1000/fps) before counter check. works perfect now. thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while for me (did something like that back at University 4 years ago), but from what I remember is the fact that not every codec available on Windows includes an encoder as well as a decoder. Most of them might be decoder only. As such some FOURCCs will work while others produce errors or simply won't work at all.

FFMPEG provides several codecs, but I think they're not available from within OpenCV: I think they're provided as DirectShow filters, while OpenCV uses the classic Video for Windows interface (I might be wrong here, so feel free to correct me on this).

The timing issue you experience is easy to explain: If you set the video's fps to 4 you'll have to ensure to only take and paste 4 images per second. Otherwise you're essentially creating a slow motion or time lapse video. There are more elegant ways, but using basic OpenCV functions this is probably the easiest solution already.

Comment: Hi, them can you point me which encoder/decoder should I use to work?